# Error, Access-Control-Allow-Origin cannot contain more than one origin

Tags: nginx

I am trying to reverse proxy the Disqus api via Nginx, but I found that the static website hosted in Github Page can not support more than one origin in header

Is there any idea to set the origin to only one or any other work around?

```
[Error] Access-Control-Allow-Origin cannot contain more than one origin.
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://***&thread=ident:technology/2019/12/10/learning-reverse-proxy/&api_key=** due to access control checks.
```

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use * for Origin?

Comment: Yep, The origin can not direct to dispus, So I am trying to proxy it via API, but it looks like that It can not be allowed by github after I set the header of the request